# python-can J1939 filter mask

Tags: python, can-bus, python-can, j1939

I have been working in a Raspberry with an MCP2515 CAN bus device for read entire values of J1939 messages on broadcasting with python .

I would like to filter the J1939 messages, but i'm not undestand the meaning of the can-mask and how I discorver that. In the docs of ***python-can*** says :

> All messages that match at least one filter are returned. If filters
> is None or a zero length sequence, all messages are matched.

```
[{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21, "extended": False}]
```

Even though I understood this 'None' part, i didn't understand how identify the mask for my ID message

Example:

I would like to just get by script just the messages with ID "0xCF00400" and "0x18fee927"

```
import can

# CAN Setting
can_interface = 'can0'
bus = can.interface.Bus(can_interface, bustype='socketcan_native')

while True:
     message = bus.recv()

     bus.set_filters([{"can_id":0xF004 , "can_mask": ?? , "extended": True},
                      {"can_id":0xfee9 , "can_mask": ?? , "extended": True}])
```

How i should fill each variable and how I determine the mask of an ID?

**UPDATING 03/10/2021**

I have tried the code below, but still returning all messages

```
import can

# CAN Setting
can_interface = 'can0'

can_filters = [{"can_id":0xCF00400, "can_mask": 0, "extended": True},
               {"can_id":0x18fee927, "can_mask": 0, "extended": True}]

bus = can.interface.Bus(can_interface, bustype='socketcan_native',can_filters=can_filters)

while True:
     message = bus.recv()
     print(message)
```

Output:

```
Timestamp: 1615382511.238233    ID: 18fee500    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.238893    ID: 18fef100    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.247038    ID: 18fef100    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.247611    ID: 18fee500    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.248222    ID: 18fee900    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.248868    ID: 0cf00400    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.257056    ID: 0cf00400    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.257623    ID: 18fee900    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.258223    ID: 18fef100    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.258827    ID: 18fee500    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.267039    ID: 18fee500    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.267624    ID: 18fef100    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.268229    ID: 0cf00400    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.268835    ID: 18fee900    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.277035    ID: 18fee900    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.277620    ID: 0cf00400    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.278220    ID: 18fee500    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1615382511.278823    ID: 18fef100    X                DLC:  8    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff     Channel: can0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `"can_id":0xCF00400, "can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF` to efficiently filter (at the kernel level) for the cob ID you want, with no mask/filter required. The mask of `0xFFFFFFF` (all mask bits set to 1) requires an exact match on the can_id.

```py
bus.set_filters([{"can_id":0xCF00400, "can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF, "extended": True},
                 {"can_id":0x18fee927, "can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF, "extended": True}])
```

For example, the documentation says:

> A filter matches, when
> `<received_can_id> & can_mask == can_id & can_mask`.
> If `extended` is set as well, it only matches messages where
> `<received_is_extended> == extended`. Else it matches every
> messages based only on the arbitration ID and mask.

So as an example:

```py
# The following just equals zero
0xCF00400 & 0 == 0 # True

# The following equals 0xCF00400 (217056256 in decimal) exactly
0xCF00400 & 0xFFFFFFF == 0xCF00400 # True
0xCF00400 & 0xFFFFFFF == 217056256 # True

# The following can_id would not get through the filter + mask:
0x18fee500 & 0xFFFFFFF == 0xCF00400 & 0xFFFFFFF # False

# The following obviously would get through the filter + mask:
0xCF00400 & 0xFFFFFFF == 0xCF00400 & 0xFFFFFFF # True
```

I'd put the `bus.set_filters()` before the `while True` loop, and before the `bus.recv`. It's a setting, so you only need to set it once at the start.

Preferable, you would add it when you initialize the bus, like this:

```py
can_filters = [{"can_id":0xCF00400, "can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF, "extended": True},
               {"can_id":0x18fee927, "can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF, "extended": True}]

bus = can.Bus(
    interface="socketcan",
    channel="can0",
    can_filters=can_filters
)
```

Also, I believe `bustype='socketcan_native'` is [deprecated](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/interfaces/socketcan.html) in favour of `interface="socketcan"`. I've been using the latter with success for quite some time, and no warning messages.

Comment: Hello, @Sean.  I've tried to test your code, but actually is not working yet
It is still returning all messages, not only the messages that i set :/

Comment: @GabrielLincoln my bad. My `"can_mask": 0` (all bits 0 or off) just lets everything through. For an exact match, try `"can_mask": 0xFFFFFFF` (all mask bits 1 or set on).

Comment: Thanks @Sean ! It is worked and also make me understand how the mask works. Also, thanks about the hint about 'socket native'